# angular 2 npm start module error

Tags: angular, module

```
src/app/app.component.ts(2,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/services/user.service'.
src/app/app.component.ts(11,4): error TS7008: Member 'users' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/app/app.module.ts(7,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/services/user.service'.
src/app/services/user.service.ts(4,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/models/user'.
```

Comment: You are importing a file which is not present.

Comment: Or there is an error in the file it's trying to import

Comment: I think your import paths are wrong, can you post directory structure?
Meanwhile try removing `app` in `app.component.ts` imports.